# What makes monero different from other anonymous coins?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

Is there a break down of how monero is different from other anonymous coins as of 2017 July?

Comment: In it's current state, this question is a duplicate.  If the question is made more specific, then maybe I won't vote to close it.  If it can't be tailored to be more unique and focused, then the question will probably have to be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by others anonymous cryptocurrencies you mean Zcash and Dash,  you can check out this article: [Monero vs Dash vs Zcash](https://moneroforcash.com/monero-vs-dash-vs-zcash-vs-bitcoinmixers.php)

Comment: Also, most other coins which claim to be private are clones from Bitcoin that have been modified to make them into "Dash" or "Zcash" or "x." Monero's code is completely different from Bitcoin and Bitcoin-clone coins, and is much more secure since privacy is by default and not optional as it is with the other coins.

Comment: Can you try to summarize the answer here on SE instead of linking to an outside source?